# What to say in a formal situation, when someone's on hold on the phone and you're ready to say something

Tags: phrase-request

Here is the specific situation I'm facing.
I called someone and they required some information (an id of some sort) which I didn't have at hand, so I asked them to hold so I could get it. After I was ready, I wanted to ask the person if they're also ready so I could spell the id out for them, however I couldn't say *"Are you ready?"*, since it was a formal situation. Instead I said *"Should I say it?"* which didn't sound right at all. What would have been the best phrase here?

Comment: You could say, "OK, I have the ID number now. *Please let me know when you're ready*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tᴚoɯɐuo's answer is the most common and usual

> OK, I have the ID number now. Please let me know when you're ready.

or

> I have it now. Are you ready?

Comment: I agree with this answer. Although the OP said, "I couldn't say 'Are you ready?' since it was a formal situation," I'm having a hard time imagining a phone call so formal that "Are you ready?" would be too informal to use.